# copy key pair to amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server

I have run into trouble

I have ec2 instance. I connected to it via ssh.
I wanted to set up POST hook for git. 
And accidentally removed authorised_keys from /.ssh directory

My question is : if I am still connected to my aws instance can I copy myKey.pem to /.ssh directory ?

I want to omit instance restore process

Thank you in advance !))

Comment: If you are still connected to the instance, then sure, you can modify the `authorized_keys` file there.  Just copy-and-paste your ssh public key (*not* the PEM-encoded private key) into the file.

Comment: @larsks where I can find ssh public key ? Please can you add steps . I'm in big trouble ((

Comment: @Roma, if you can't find the public key that corresponds to your current `.pem` file, just generate a new key pair, and add that public key!  You could use AWS to do this, or check out these popular instructions from GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: @JoshPadnick, thank you , that's what i did. that solved my problem !) If you move your comment to answer I will accept it ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find the public key that corresponds to your current `.pem` file, just generate a new key pair, and add that public key to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file! You could use AWS to generate the new key pair, or check out these popular instructions from GitHub: help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys.